# Angular Fire Auth signInWithEmailLink Not Working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

On My backend nodejs server I am doing the following:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

...

async function sendEmailVerificationLink(email: string): Promise<ExitMessage> {

  const transporter: Transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'support@my_domain.com',
        pass: SUPPORT_GMAIL_PASS
    }
  });

  const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: 'https://my_firebase_app.firebaseapp.com/',
    handleCodeInApp: true
  };

  const verificationLink = await admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(email, actionCodeSettings);


  const parsedUrl = url.parse(verificationLink, true);

  const oobCode = parsedUrl.query.oobCode;


  const finalLink = 'https://my_domain.uc.r.appspot.com?url=my_domain://signup-verification?email=' + email + "%26oobCode=" + oobCode;

  const mailOptions = {
      from: 'support@my_domain.com',
      to: email,
      subject: 'Confirmation Link',
      text: 'This is your Email Confirmation Link: ' + finalLink
  };

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {

            console.log((new Date).toUTCString() + 'transporter.sendMail sendEmailVerificationLink: ', error);
            winstonLogger.info((new Date).toUTCString() + 'transporter.sendMail sendEmailVerificationLink: ', error);

            const exit: ExitMessage = {
              exit: 15,
              success: false,
            };

            resolve(exit);

        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);

            const exit: ExitMessage = {
              exit: 16,
              success: true,
            };

            resolve(exit);

        }

    });
  });

}
```

When the link generated is clicked, it goes to my angular site: https://my_domain.uc.r.appspot.com
where the following happens in my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.openDeepLink();
  }

  openDeepLink() {
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const deepLink = urlParams.get('url');

    // Redirect to the deep link
    if (deepLink) {
      
      const decodedDeepLink = decodeURIComponent(deepLink);
      this.displayDeepLink = decodedDeepLink;
  
      window.location.href = decodedDeepLink;

    }
  }
```

Finally, window.location.href = decodedDeepLink; opens up my Ionic 6 App (currently testing on Android), which is listening for the deep link in app.component.ts, and finally routes it to my signup-verification page where the following happens:

```
const email = history.state.email;
const oobCode = history.state.oobCode;

const continueUrl = 'https://my_firebase_app.firebaseapp.com';


const emailLink = 'https://my_firebase_app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode='+ oobCode + '&continueUrl=' + continueUrl + '&lang=en';


try {
      await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailLink(email, emailLink).then( ...
```

I then get the error:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).

When logging in my backend code, the full link generated by

```
const verificationLink = await admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(email, actionCodeSettings);
```

is:
https://my_firebase_app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=MY_API_KEY&mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=MY_OOB_CODE&continueUrl=my_firebase_app.firebaseapp.com/&lang=en

I am currently testing this on an android device and have verified the email and oobCode are correct.

When I google it, I cannot find any documentation for AngularFireAuth: signInWithEmailLink.

The closest I get is:

```
(property) signInWithEmailLink: (email: string, emailLink?: string) => Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential>
Asynchronously signs in using an email and sign-in email link. If no link is passed, the link is inferred from the current URL.

Fails with an error if the email address is invalid or OTP in email link expires.

Note: Confirm the link is a sign-in email link before calling this method firebase.auth.Auth.isSignInWithEmailLink.

@example

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, emailLink)
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Some error occurred, you can inspect the code: error.code
      // Common errors could be invalid email and invalid or expired OTPs.
    });
@param email — The email account to sign in with.

@param emailLink
The optional link which contains the OTP needed to complete the sign in with email link. If not specified, the current URL is used instead.
```

I am assuming the OTP is the oobCode, but I think that I am constructing my link wrong (as per the error).

I have checked the following:
Make sure that the email address you are using to sign in matches the one that was used to generate the email verification link.

Double-check that the oobCode in the link matches the one passed to the signInWithEmailLink method.

Ensure that the continueUrl parameter matches the URL configured in the Firebase Console for your app's email action handler.

Make sure that the email verification link has not expired. The default expiration time for these links is 1 hour, but it can be customized when generating the link.

Check that you have enabled the email link sign-in provider in the Firebase Console for your app.

Confirm that the signInWithEmailLink method is being called with the correct arguments.

Check the Firebase Console for any error messages related to authentication.

None of these are wrong. I am assuming I am constructing my emailLink incorrectly, but cannot find the right format.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with Ionic. More of a nodeJS issue.